# Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to install packages offline (`dietaryindex`). What I do is based on a previously asked question as follows:

```r
install.packages("~/Downloads/jamesjiadazhan-dietaryindex-update-247-gb0fe885.tar", 
   repos = NULL)
```

> Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'

system is RStudio 2021.09.0+351 "Ghost Orchid" Release  for macOS

I get the error I mentioned in the title. is there someone out to give me an advice ?

Comment: try `type = "source"` ?

Comment: R packages are typically in files with extension `tar.gz`, not just `.tar`.  Are you sure that's an R package?